# "Try-catch" totally being omitted by code

Tags: android, eclipse, try-catch, screenshot

I have this code which is meant to take screenshots. I had it up and running perfectly fine in one of my apps which I was using as a "rough draft".

However, now that I copied the code into my original project, it seems like the code never really enters the "try" portion. This is kind of confusing since it is still running fine on the other sample app but not here. And just for your information, no errors are being posted either. What is happening here?

```
public void getScreen()
{
    View table = findViewById(R.id.TransactionLog);
    table.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    table.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(table.getDrawingCache());
    table.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // Clear drawing cache

    File doc = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "TransactionHistory.png");

    try
    {
        doc.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(doc);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        sendmail();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug, where does it stop if it doesn't get to the try/catch?

Comment: Add a log statment to the try-catch the see if it is being tried.

Comment: add Log.v("ACTIVITY", "In Try-catch");

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: Where exactly should I place that line? Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: i think your going to need to post more code.  if this code works in another application than im fairly certain its not this piece of code, but the surrounding code

Comment: Place it at the beginning of try - catch

Comment: Make sure you are calling the method getScreen() where it can be ran, and its not in a loop or if() statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as all the other suggestions made, it could be throwing an exception on the line:

```
File doc = new File.....
```

in which case it will never enter your try/catch. Put some logging statements or debugging breakpoints at the beginning of the method and anywhere the method is being called.